# AudioClip Progress bar in Java

Tags: java, audio, progress-bar

I created an audio Player using java applet but i'm stuck at trying to create a progress bar, no need for seek or anything fancy, just a progress bar displaying the progress of the audio file being played.

I don't know how to get the current progress off the AudioClip, that's my main problem among other small things. any hints would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AudioClip for that; you'll have to use the [javax.sound API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html). The great [Example Depot](http://www.exampledepot.com/) has good sample code to get you started.

Here's [how to load and playback an audio file](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.sound.sampled/Load.html).

Here's [how to query the clip for its current position](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.sound.sampled/GetTime.html).

Comment: This site is now dead, domain is for sale and links to garbage.

Comment: This is yet another excellent example of why pasting links to code is a horrible idea.